# How to add sidebar drawer with react native navigation v2?

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

With react-native-navigation v1 you can set up a drawer like this:

```
drawer: {
    left: {
        screen: 'ScreenName'
    }
}
```

In docs of react-native-navigation they mention that drawer is still supported,
[image: drawer support]

but there in no example of its usage. I tried with same way as in v1, but it didn't work. Is there anyone who has achieved it somehow?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In RNN V2 and up you can add Drawer with simply using sideMenu instead of old drawer option Ex :

```
Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
  Navigation.setRoot({
    root: {
      sideMenu: {
        id: "sideMenu",
        left: {
          component: {
            id: "Drawer",
            name: "navigation.Drawer"
          }
        },
        center: {
          stack: {
            id: "AppRoot",
            children: [{
              component: {
                id: "App",
                name: "navigation.AppScreen"
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

[Take a look at this](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/before-you-start/) and navigate to sideMenu

and in order to close the drawer use Navigation.mergeOptions and pass visible false like this

```
<Button onPress={this.hideSideMenu}/>

hideSideMenu() {
  Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId, {
    sideMenu: {
      left: {
        visible: false
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: and can you please tell how to disable at a certain page

Comment: @pkyeck without implementing the hideSideMenu I get instance.render() is undefined error. Any idea why this is? I am trying to recreate your side menu

Comment: @user2763557 I just edited the answer - it is devoka's answer

Comment: @devoka, could you assist with my error? i can't find anything on google...

Comment: The link is broken.